# How to create DNS A Record usin Azure CLI or Terraform

Tags: azure, dns, terraform, azure-cli

I'm trying to automate DNS record creation in Azure Portal and wondering if there is any possibility to create Alias A DNS record which points to another Azure Resource like Public IP address instead of being IP record?

Looking to do this using Azure CLI or Terraform.

[image: AWS Screenshot]

Regards,
Areg

Comment: This is not a programming question in the sense of the SO policies. You would probably be better off asking that on serverfault.com or similar sites.

Comment: Terraform does not support this yet. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3624

Comment: Thanks @Binarus I will follow up rules.

Comment: Thanks @AmanGarg-MSFT - I will follow it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an empty A record with `--target-resource` which points to another Azure Resource ID in the Azure CLI [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/record-set/a?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-dns-record-set-a-create) like this:

```
az network dns record-set a create -g myrg -n aaa -z example.com --target-resource "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/vmb-ip"
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't immediately ask the question asker to accept your answer. There could easily be another answer that is better fit for the question asker and this could be discouraged by a very early acceptance.

Comment: @NancyXiong - Terraform is already creating empty record which I point to Public IP then. I will see how I can automate second part.

Comment: @vrtareg Terraform does no built-in support `target-resource` currently, refer to [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/dns_a_record.html#argument-reference), so as a workaround, you could use provisioner "local-exec" to invoke the Azure CLI commands in your terraform code. Read more details [here](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/how-to-handle-unsupported-azure-features-in-terraform/).

Answer (score 1):

```
resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "dns_zone" {
  name                = "bolivia.bo"
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name

  tags = {
    Environment = "QA"
    Team        = "Yes"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "dns_a_record" {
  name                = "@"
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.dns_zone.name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  ttl                 = 3600
  target_resource_id  = var.public_ip_id
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "dns_www_a_record" {
  name                = "www"
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.dns_zone.name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  ttl                 = 3600
  target_resource_id  = var.public_ip_id
}

resource "azurerm_dns_cname_record" "dns_api_cname_record" {
  name                = "api"
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.dns_zone.name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  ttl                 = 3600
  record              = azurerm_dns_zone.dns_zone.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Terraform module that has as a variable of the target resource for the A Record value, let's imagine the following scenario:

```
> "Record"          "TTL"      "RecordType"  "Target"
> www.contoso.com   3600   IN  A             1.1.1.1
```

Where "1.1.1.1" is the Address of the resource you want to link, for this example will be a [azurerm_public_ip](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/public_ip.html)

You could use the following:

```
variable "target_ip" {
   type        = str
   description = "Target Resource address"
}

variable "record_a_name" {
   type        = str
   description = "Target Resource address"
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "contoso_rg" {
  name     = "acceptanceTestResourceGroup1"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "contoso_dns" {
  name                = "contoso.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "contoso_dns_a_record" {
  name                = var.record_a_name
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.contoso_dns.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.contoso_rg.name
  ttl                 = 300

  records = [var.target_ip]

}
```

Whereas you can call the module this way:

```
data "azurerm_public_ip" "target_resource" {
  name                = "<name_of_resource_target>"
}


module "dns_example" {
  source = "<path_to_module>"

  record_a_name = "www"
  target_ip     = azurerm_public_ip.target_resource.ip_address  
}
```

As a side note, above code is far from being production quality, it is only to show how can be accomplished. I would also make TTL and Tags dynamic, I would decouple records from the zone and resource group declaration, among other good practices.

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/dns_ns_record.html